# Why is the IEnumerable behaving strangely

Tags: c#, linq

I have a code as below:

```
var userTest =
    from u in userUpdated
    select (u.Field<string>("Emp Birthdate"));

var userTest1 = 
    from u in original
    select (u.Field<string>("Date of Birth"));
```

Value of both the fields are same, i.e. EmpBirthdate and Date of Birth, its as "05 March 1985".

I gave an comparer using the code as:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> records =
    from u in updateRecords
    join o in OriginalRecords
        on u.Field<string>("Employee ID")
        equals o.Field<int>(" Employee Identity No").ToString()
    where (u.Field<string>("Date of Birth") != 
        o.Field<string>("Emp Birthdate"))
```

It does not match, the above records.count() is not equal to 0.

What is the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are the fields of type string in the datatable?

Comment: Is there any chance that the values are stored in char fields with differing length, i.e. CHAR(20) and CHAR(30)?

Comment: @Matt-dot-net , yes both the fields are of string, Infact the table updateRecords, holds the value that is read from the excel sheet. and the OriginalRecords is a datatable, but the datetime field is stored in string                                             @Lazarus, no it is not stored in different length                                                               I use the Ienumerable to compare two datatable

Answer (score 2):

What are you querying with this syntax?

It is generally considered bad practice to use strings like this.  A strongly typed adapter would be better and would allow you to access `u.EmployeeId` instead of `u.Field<string>("Employee ID")`.  My guess is that this practice is the cause of your problem.  Perhaps you are typing a field name incorrectly.  I can't think of any situation where a field name would begin with a space as in `" Employee Identity No"`.  I actually can't think of a situation where spaces are used at all.

However, without more information, nobody will be able to help you.  We need  to know what you are querying, what the schema looks like, and why your syntax looks like this.  The best answer you will get without providing that is that the most likely cause of your problem is a malformed magic string.

Comment: I use the Ienumerable to compare two datatable , I read the data and populate in excel sheet, I am working on VSTO. The data that is read and populated in the excel sheet is stored in Original Records. The user modifies the records, which I will be saving. There are 2500 rows and 92 columns, so I just take the record that has been modified and update it. UpdateRecords is the datatable that is read from the excel sheet and populated into datatable. In both places the data is string only, its not a conversion issue.